# I want to make a method that subtracts 25 from an my hp value, but there is an issue

Tags: java

So far i have this if logic

```
if (d.intersects(r1) && en.visible == true && en.isAlive == false)
{
    hit = 25;
    // System.out.println(enemy_count);
    hitmang(hit);
}

if (d.intersects(r2) && en2.visible == true && en2.isAlive == false)
{
    hit = 25;
    hitmang(hit);
    //  System.out.println(enemy_count);
}
```

with this method

```
private void hitmang(int x) { 
    p.user_hp = p.user_hp - x;
}
```

these are both my enemies

```
en = new Enemy(700, 150);
en2 = new Enemy (980, 150);
```

I want to make it so that when i hit the enemy it only subtracts 25 hp from me, but because the area of the enemy is large (113, 134) it is subtracting 25 until i leave that range making my hp ~-6000 (obviously an issue), is there a way to make it so it only subtracts once.

Comment: Knockback or cool down before able to be hit again

Answer (score 1):

I guess that because your first fragment of code is in the game loop which run many times a second (usually 30 times). In every execution (which runs every about 0.03 seconds) your shape *is* intersecting an enemy (because you didn't move away).

That said, your HP decreases 25 every 0.03 seconds until you move away from an enemy!

Try this:

First, initialize a `hitted` field in your Player class.

```
private boolean hitted = false;
```

Then, in your game loop.

```
if (d.intersects(r1) && en.visible == true && en.isAlive == false && !p.hitted)
{
    hit = 25;
    // System.out.println(enemy_count);
    hitmang(hit);
    p.hitted = true;
}

// Same goes to 2nd enemy ....

// if no longer intersects
if (!d.intersects(r1) && !d.intersects(r2)){
    p.hitted = false;
}
```

---

or you may want to implement cool-down mechanism as per comments.

if it is what you want to do, initialize another field instead

```
private int hitSince = 0;
```

Then, in your game loop.

```
if (d.intersects(r1) && en.visible == true && en.isAlive == false && hitSince <= 0)
{
    hit = 25;
    // System.out.println(enemy_count);
    hitmang(hit);
    hitSince = 30; // once hit, you won't be 'hit' and lose HP again in 30 frames
}

// Same goes to 2nd enemy ....

// decrease cooldown time every frame
hitSince--;
```

If you go this way, you may want to consider using a `Timer` though, as this code would depends on FPS of your game - which could be unstable in other player's computer (because their computer is slow or running an anti-virus in the background, for example. This is commonly dubbed (from gamers) as "lag")

btw, if there will be a lot of enemies, you would need to store them in an `array` or a `collection` such as `ArrayList`

Comment: I would change to "hit" for grammatical reasons but otherwise this is a very good system that I have used extensively in my own games. However, I would recommend using a timer to reset the hit variable to false such that the player cannot become immune to damage simply by standing in an enemy.

Comment: I don't use `hit` because OA already has a local variable named `hit` lol. A timer would be good too, but I didn't use a timer personally...

Comment: the 2nd character does not do any damage now? any tips?

Comment: Apply the same code to the 2nd character. I leave the `// Same goes to 2nd enemy ....` for you :)

Comment: how would i implement the timer?

Comment: if (d.intersects(r1) && en.visible == true && en.isAlive == false && !p.hitting)
 {
     
     
     hitmang(hit);
     p.hitting = true;
 }

 // Same goes to 2nd enemy ....

 if (d.intersects(r1) && en.visible == true && en.isAlive == false && !p.hitting)
 {  
    
              hitmang(hit);
              p.hitting = true;
 }
     if (!d.intersects(r1) && !d.intersects(r2)){
        p.hitting = false;
 }
 
 }

Comment: The second `if` conditions should be `d.intersects(r2)`... You should think and understand before applying other's code.

Comment: i am very sorry, its about midnight where i live, and i was leaving this post for the morning until i saw you answer. Thank you for helping me, sorry for my retardation i have been coding since about 10 hours. excuses aside you are right. Thanks again man.